# Searching shortcut for selecting multiple files in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I developed a little bot which do some stuff on a website.
At a moment, the website open file selector dialog and the bot should select 3 files and confirm.

On windows 10 it simply paste the paths of the files ("path1 path2 path3") in dialog input and confirm.

On Ubuntu file dialog (Nautilus), there is not an input, but I discovered a way to display a search bar with CTRL+L. From here I can paste one path and it work, but unfortunately not with multiple paths.

"Error when getting information for file "path1, path2": No such file or directory"

Is there any way to achieve to this ? If yes, how please

Comment: So your achievement requires to press Ctrl L and then want to select 3 paths?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but I believe your question is missing some important details. You mention a website but I presume your "bot" works with a web browser, so if you see a file selector it might come from that web browser, not Nautilus. If you look at sites that allow you to select more than one file at a time (such as Google Photos) they present an area of the browser window you can drag multiple files onto. That may be your best option to interact with Nautilus in that manner.